# How to get js files generated by tsc to format to ESLint

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, tsc

When I run build my TS project, the JS files are a mess of indent, double quote, semi, camelcase and brace-stye errors.  I am using ESLint recommendations to format my TS files.

What are some ways I can control the js formatting at build so that the js files satisfy EsLint rules?

Comment: You should treat your JS output when you compile your TS files as the equivalent of "machine code" you'd get from other compiled languages. They are not meant to be tidy and human understood. Don't configure EsLint to try to lint them

Comment: Thank you, I added .js to ignored patterns in EsLint config. Is there is a more customary way to not lint js files.

Comment: Usually a typescript project outputs the js files in a different folder e.g. you'd put sources in ./src and the output would go in ./build or ./dist or ./lib or something like that and you'd set your source root (for linting and tsconfig) to ./src